# How variable scope of $scope in angular js works?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am a beginner to angular JS and I found this code in the tutorial.

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
  ];
});
```

This code is working fine but I want to know how the variable scope of `$scope` works. From the code, it seems the `$scope` is a local variable and its scope is limited only to the function.

Then why cant I change the name of the `$scope` variable? If I change the variable name in all occurrences inside the function, it doesn't seems to work

Comment: $scope is where you hold values and functions that you want to be visible to the user. Anything you want to bind to an element, you add to $scope. Read about the digest cycle if you want to learn more about this.
  
> What surprises me is the that when the name of the variable $scope change, the code doesn't seems to work.
  
This is because angular uses dependency injection all over the place.

Comment: my doubt is more javascript than angular js. How does the value of variable $scope is obtained outside the function block ? its not returning the $scope also $scope is not global

Comment: Outside angular or controller function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular uses dependency injection. $scope is an injected value. It is essentially an object containing all of the `ng-` references inside of the relative controller for that module.

> "A module is a collection of services, directives, controllers, filters, and configuration information." -[angular source](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.js)

When you access something from the collection a module contains, the scope of that access is injected. For example, when a module is created, the module creates a controller property

```
/**
* @ngdoc method
* @name angular.Module#controller
* @module ng
* @param {string|Object} name Controller name, or an object map of controllers where the
 *    keys are the names and the values are the constructors.
 * @param {Function} constructor Controller constructor function.
 * @description
 * See {@link ng.$controllerProvider#register $controllerProvider.register()}.
 */
 controller: invokeLater('$controllerProvider', 'register'),
```

This property is registered with the controllerProvider.

> The controller is injectable (and supports bracket notation) with the following >locals:
>   *
>   * * `$scope` - Current scope associated with the element

So when you are using this code

```
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope){
```

What you are doing is accessing the `'PhoneListCtrl` controller from the controller provider, and then the function provided is called with the associated scope stored with the `PhoneListCtrl` for that module.

With specific regards to the variable name `$scope`, the reason that angular can tell if you are using this "keyword" is through a regex process. If you use .toString() on a function it will convert the entire thing to a string, and you can then parse it to see what was in the function. Angular does this,

> "The simplest form is to extract the dependencies from the arguments of the function. This is done by converting the function into a string using `toString()` method and extracting the argument names."

The regex is defined in angular as `var FN_ARGS = /^function\s*[^\(]*\(\s*([^\)]*)\)/m;` You can test using this at https://regex101.com/r/qL4gM8/1

[image]

So that is how Angular knows that you used the variable `$scope` in your function parameters.

Comment: The last part of your answer cleared my doubt. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MS, just to add to Travis's answer. This kind of regex-matching of of function parameters does not withstand minification, which is why [explicit annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#the-array-notation) is needed when minifying the code

Answer (score 2):

From AngularJS Docs:

> Scope is the **glue between application controller and the view**...
>   Both controllers and directives have reference to the scope, but not
>   to each other.

$scope is created by angular and injected (dependency injection) into your controller function by refference.

Think about this simple javascript sample an then expand your thoughts to AngularJS

```
(function() {
     // var myscope is not global. it's in the closure
     // of my anonymous function
     var myscope = {
        "samplekey" : "samplevalue"
     }

     // .... You can do anything with scope

     // Imagine this function as your controller
     function myController($scope) {
        // Here I can work with $scope variable
        $scope.data = { "anotherkey" : "anothervalue" };
        console.log($scope.samplekey); // It works fine
     }

     // inject myscope into the controller function
     myController(myscope);

     // I can access the new property added to myscope variable
     // by the controller function (maybe I can use it in a view).  
     console.log(myscope.data.anotherkey); // anothervalue 

}());
```

You can use any variable you want as scope in AngularJS as well. But you have to specify that the variable you created is referencing the scope variable.

```
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl',['$scope', function(varAsScope) {
  varAsScope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S', 'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi', 'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™', 'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
  ];
}]);
```

Here is a [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uv939sqe/1/)

Comment: my doubt is more javascript than angular js. How does the value of variable $scope is obtained outside the function block ? its not returning the $scope also $scope is not global

Comment: I've updated my answer trying to explain how Angular inject a scope variable into your controller

Comment: If I change the name of the variable `$scope` inside your function. It still works fine. But in angular, i doesn't work. And that is my doubt. Why cant I change a variable name inside the funciton scope in angular js

Comment: could u please make it the other way around? .i.e. can you make your code such a way that the $scope variable is not modifiable. or if I modify the $scope variable in your code, it works differently ?

Answer (score 0):

Everything in angular starts with $ is a service here scope is also the the service which binds view with controller and allow you to use **TWO WAY BINDING**.

Yes $scope is limited to a particular component we can say directive or the controller.But we have father's of scope as well $rootScope.

So you can use $rootScope as a service for global stuff.

Hope it clears your doubt.

Few links that will help are follows :-

[Github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)(Best resource)

[Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

Comment: my doubt is more javascript than angular. How does the value of  variable $scope is obtained outside the function block ? its not returning the $scope also $scope is not global

Comment: outside angular or just single controller ?

Comment: Simple send $scope to other function as a variable if you are calling it fron inside the angular side for example i want to call add() function i can call it like add($scope) and send the simple scope and extract its value :-)

Comment: I am not sure whether you have understood my question. Suppose we have a function function fun(a){ a = "Hello"}, there is now way the value of variable a is obtained outside the scope of the function. But in the example shown value is obtained outside the function. Also, inside the function the variable name doesn't matter. i.e. function fun(b){b="Hello'} should also work. But in the above example, if we change the $scope to say $scope2 in all places inside the function, it dosen't seems to work